"Select for Compare" + "Compare with Selected" option in VSCode on linux for two moderately large files on ssh takes for ever
I have two moderately large trace files (generated using python hunter) on a server which I access using ssh.
/media/abhishek/outputs$ ls -lh *trace.txt
-rw-rw-r-- 1 abhishek abhishek 140M May 18 00:01 DALLE2_pytorch_accuracy_test_patched_torch_trace.txt
-rw-rw-r-- 1 abhishek abhishek  97M May 18 00:16 DALLE2_pytorch_accuracy_test_trace.txt

I want to compare the traces by using "Select for Compare" for the first trace and then do "Compare with selected" on the second trace.
But it takes forever to load and I get a blank screen with a blue bar going left to right:

There is no issue with other smaller traces, but I don't understand what is the issue happening with these two particular traces.
Initially the editor was complaining of a large file size > 10 MB. So I changed the workbench.EditorLargeFileConfirmation to 200 MB:

I guess I have sufficient memory on my host system (from which I am running the vscode and accessing the remote machine):
$ free -h
               total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:            31Gi        21Gi       1.7Gi       521Mi       8.5Gi       9.3Gi
Swap:          4.0Gi       0.0Ki       4.0Gi       521Mi       8.5Gi       9.3Gi

Any way around for this issue?
